# Persistent Variables in ExecutorService (Java)

Tags: java, concurrency, threadpool

I've created a pool of 4 worker threads to process some files. In the test there's about 200 of them. The thread pool version is already about 3 times faster than doing it sequentially but there is room for improvement.

The biggest bottleneck (ignoring disk I/O) is that I need to instantiate a new MessageDigest object. In the single threaded version I just had 1. In this version I have 200.

What I was wondering was, is it possible to have a variable local to the thread in the work pool? That way (assuming no threads die) there would only be four instances of the MessageDigest object rather than 200...

Each task requires the digest so I'm not sure if there's a better way to do it...

### UPDATE

I tried to use a ThreadLocal object but where should I create it? If I create it in the task itself, I guess it goes out of context when the task is completed. Each time a new instance is created. The code I have is:

```
    ThreadLocal<GenerateSHA1> tl = new ThreadLocal<GenerateSHA1>();

    hashMaker = tl.get();
    if(hashMaker == null){
        hashMaker = new GenerateSHA1();
        tl.set(hashMaker);
    }
```

This is done from inside the constructor of the task.

UPDATE

Okay making it static sort of works in that the object is not lost - but it's now highlighted a different issue. The work "tasks" are create in the Main thread and then added to the the ExecutorService with invokeAll().

Any ideas on how to work around this?

Comment: Take a look at java.lang.ThreadLocal: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html

Comment: Tried that, let me update my question...

Comment: Have you tried making the ThreadLocal static?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extend `ThreadLocal` for your class and override the `initialValue()` method. By default, it returns null.

```
private static class ThreadLocalGenerateSHA1 extends
  ThreadLocal<GenerateSHA1> {

  @Override
  protected GenerateSHA1 initialValue() {
    return new GenerateSHA1();
  }

}

private static final ThreadLocalGenerateSHA1 generateSHA1 = new ThreadLocalGenerateSHA1();

...
```

On the tasks, simply call the `get()` method of generateSHA1. You do not need to call `set()`.

Comment: Where do I use this code? If I create a new Java class, for the ThreadLocalGenerateSHA1 it says that it can't be static and I'm not sure where else to put it...

Comment: It only needs to be static if it is a inner class. You can also remove the `static` if you create a top level class.

Answer (score 0):

You can take help of [beforeExecute](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#beforeExecute%28java.lang.Thread,%20java.lang.Runnable%29) and [afterExecute](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#afterExecute%28java.lang.Runnable,%20java.lang.Throwable%29) methods of the ThreadPoolExecutor by extending it. In your extended class, create 4 MessageDigest objects and assign them to each task in beforeExecute(...) in a round-robin fashion.

```
private static final Executor executor = new MyThreadPoolExecutor(10, 10, 50000L,   TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(100));
```

## EDIT

I feel the object pool option mentioned by Ravi Bhatt as the simple and elegant idea. Create a pool and let the task ask for the MessageDigest from the pool.

Comment: Any example on how to do that with an ExecutorService? Specifically the newFixedThreadPool?

Comment: ThreadPoolExecutor  is an implementation of ExecutorService...so not sure what your question is. When you call Executors.newFixedThreadPool(...) it internally creates ThreadPoolExecutor like this "new ThreadPoolExecutor(nThreads, nThreads, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>())"

Comment: I think using a ThreadLocal is a more common way to use a single object for every thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an object pool for your message digest objects. And set the pool size to 4 in your case.

apache commons provides excellent pool api:
http://commons.apache.org/pool/